# SQL Server - Get weekly and daily totals in the same query

Tags: sql-server, date

In my query I currently have it working to get the total sum of fields within a set date range, I also want the query to show the totals for a single day also.

For example my current outcome is like this:

```
ID, UserID, uname, totals
1     1     admin   3
2     3     test    6
3     4     user    2
```

I want my outcome like this:

```
ID, UserID, uname, totals, todaytotal
1     1     admin   3,      1
2     3     test    6,      2
3     4     user    2,      2
```

The data here is random but just for visual purpose.

The totals is getting the sum of quantity from a table named ActivityLog

My Query is like this, working with a date range:

```
SELECT al.UserID, 
od.CardNumber as uname, 
Sum(isnull(cast(ActualQuantity as float),0)) totals
from ActivityLog al , OperatorDetail od 
WHERE
od.ID = al.UserID AND
StartDateTime >= '2014-08-24 00:00:00.000' 
AND EndDateTime <= '2014-08-31 23:59:59.000' 
group by al.UserID, od.CardNumber
order by od.CardNumber
```

This is what I've tried to try get totals from a specific date (todaytotal on 2014-08-29)

```
SELECT al.UserID, 
od.CardNumber as uname, 
Sum(isnull(cast(ActualQuantity as float),0)) totals,

(select Sum(isnull(cast(ACTL.ActualQuantity as float),0)) totaltoday 
from ActivityLog ACTL, OperatorDetail OPD 
WHERE
ACTL.UserID = OPD.ID
AND
al.StartDateTime >= '2014-08-29 00:00:00.000'  -- same date (one day)
AND al.EndDateTime <= '2014-08-29 23:59:59.000'  -- same date (one day)
GROUP BY ACTL.UserID, OPD.CardNumber
) as todaytotal

from ActivityLog al , OperatorDetail od 
WHERE 
od.ID = al.UserID AND
StartDateTime >= '2014-08-24 00:00:00.000' 
AND EndDateTime <= '2014-08-31 23:59:59.000' 
group by al.UserID, od.CardNumber, al.StartDateTime, al.EndDateTime
order by od.CardNumber
```

With this I get this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your query is syntactically correct.

Writing from memory: Try

```
SELECT al.UserID, 
  od.CardNumber as uname, 
  Sum(isnull(cast(ActualQuantity as float),0)) totals,
  Sum(case when cast(StartDateTime as date) = cast(getdate() as date) then isnull(cast(ActualQuantity as float),0)) else 0 end) TodayTotals
from ActivityLog al , OperatorDetail od 
WHERE
  od.ID = al.UserID AND
  StartDateTime >= '2014-08-24 00:00:00.000' 
  AND EndDateTime <= '2014-08-31 23:59:59.000' 
 group by al.UserID, od.CardNumber
order by od.CardNumber
```

`CAST` to `date` works SQL SERVER >= 2008

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select al.UserID, 
       od.CardNumber as uname, 
       isnull(Sum(cast(ActualQuantity as float)), 0) totals,
       isnull(Sum(case when StartDateTime >= '2014-08-31' and StartDateTime < '2014-09-01'
                       then cast(ActualQuantity as float)
                  end), 0))  totals,
from ActivityLog al join
     OperatorDetail od 
     on od.ID = al.UserID 
where StartDateTime >= '2014-08-24' AND EndDateTime < '2014-09-01' 
group by al.UserID, od.CardNumber
order by od.CardNumber ;
```

Notice that I changed the date arithmetic.  Instead of using `<=` for the upper bound, use `<` for the next date.  Then you don't have to worry about anything that happens a fraction of a second before midnight.

I fixed the `join` syntax.  Also, I put the `isnull()` *outside* the `sum()` rather than inside.  This will give a value of `0` even when there are no matches to the `case`.  And, you should be storing `ActualQuantity` as a numeric value, so the `cast()` should be unnecessary.

Finally, if you want this for the current date:

```
       isnull(Sum(case when StartDateTime >= cast(getdate() as date) and StartDateTime < cast(getdate() + 1 as date)
                       then cast(ActualQuantity as float)
                  end), 0))  totals,
```

Do be sure that the current date is in the range used for the `where`.

Comment: I didn't get this line of yours, pardon me if I am asking nooby question : StartDateTime >= cast(getdate() as date) and StartDateTime < cast(getdate() + 1 as date). I mean the purpose behind it. and should we not just use CAST(StartDateTime AS DATE) = CAST(GetDate() AS DATE) as it will return the day for that day itself? 0.0

Comment: @Codeek . . . In the `case` statement, it doesn't make a difference.  However, in a `where` clause it does.  You want to avoid having columns as arguments to functions in the `where` and `on` clauses, because that prevents the use of indexes.

Comment: Thanx a loads :) Learnt something new :)

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is because your subquery calculating sum for today's total was returning multiple values for column. why to create entirely independent subquery. I don't find any need in you subquery to join it with OLD, just use the data available from outsid. You can do it like this

```
SELECT al.UserID, 
od.CardNumber as uname, 
Sum(isnull(cast(ActualQuantity as float),0)) totals,

(select Top 1 Sum(isnull(cast(ACTL.ActualQuantity as float),0)) totaltoday 
from ActivityLog ACTL
WHERE
ACTL.UserID = a1.ID            --OPD.ID Commented this just use a1's id
AND
CAST (StartDateTime AS DATETIME) = GETDATE() -- logically today's date should be GETDATE isn't it?
) as todaytotal

from ActivityLog al , OperatorDetail od 
WHERE 
od.ID = al.UserID AND
StartDateTime >= '2014-08-24 00:00:00.000' 
AND EndDateTime <= '2014-08-31 23:59:59.000' 
group by al.UserID, od.CardNumber, al.StartDateTime, al.EndDateTime
order by od.CardNumber
```

I'll say this However, your way is not very efficient, use what Gordan Linoff suggested